# Function not being called in ComponentDidMount

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router-v4

Not really sure how to move forward on this one. I have a (fairly) simple setup with `react-router`, almost everything works as expected - I get requests and responses between the app and my api - except I have a function I expect to run from my app's `componentDidMount` lifecycle function, but it's somehow not getting hit...

Here's a pretty minimal version of my code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { Switch } from 'react-router';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { authenticate, unauthenticate } from './actions/session';
import RouteAuthenticated from './RouteAuthenticated'; // Route if authenticated
import RedirectAuthenticated from './RedirectAuthenticated'; // Redirect to login if not authenticated
import Home from './Home';
import Login from './Login';
import Signup from './Signup';

class App extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    const token = localStorage.getItem('token'); // eslint-disable-line no-undef
    console.info(token);    // <====   Shows a token, great!
    console.info(this.props.authenticate.toString()); // Output below
    if (token) {
      console.info(`We have a token`); // <=== I get to here
      this.props.authenticate(); // <=== Never gets run...????
    } else {
      this.props.unauthenticate();
    }
  }
  render() {
    const { isAuthenticated, willAuthenticate } = this.props;
    const authProps = { isAuthenticated, willAuthenticate };
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Header />
        <Switch>
          <RouteAuthenticated exact path="/" component={Home} {...authProps} />
          <RedirectAuthenticated exact path="/login" component={Login} {...authProps} />
          <RedirectAuthenticated exact path="/signup" component={Signup} {...authProps} />
        </Switch>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

App.propTypes = {
  authenticate: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  unauthenticate: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  isAuthenticated: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
  willAuthenticate: PropTypes.bool.isRequired
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  isAuthenticated: state.isAuthenticated,
  willAuthenticate: state.willAuthenticate
});

const mapDispatchToProps = () => ({
  authenticate,
  unauthenticate
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(App);
```

And since this seemed super weird, I decided to go ahead and just make sure that there actually *was* a function to run.  I put in the `console.info(this.props.authenticate.toString());` line above, and here's what I get, which looks fine except that it never actually runs:

```
function authenticate() {
  return function (dispatch) {
    console.info("auth function");
    dispatch({
      type: 'AUTHENTICATION_REQUEST'
    });
    try {
      console.info("AUTHing");
      setCurrentUser(dispatch, _api2.default.get('is-auth'));
    } catch (e) {
      console.info("AUTH ERROR");
      localStorage.removeItem('token'); // eslint-disable-line no-undef
      window.location = '/login'; // eslint-disable-line no-undef
    }
  };
}
```

And here is the original function:

```
export const authenticate = () => (dispatch) => {
  console.info("auth function"); // <=== never called?
  dispatch({
    type: 'AUTHENTICATION_REQUEST'
  });
  try {
    console.info("AUTHing");
    setCurrentUser(dispatch, api.get('is-auth'));
  } catch (e) {
    console.info("AUTH ERROR");
    localStorage.removeItem('token');
    window.location = '/login';
  }
};
```

And the store:

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import { routerMiddleware } from 'react-router-redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import history from './history';
import reducers from './reducers';

const middleWare = [thunk, routerMiddleware(history)];
const createStoreWithMiddleware = applyMiddleware(...middleWare)(createStore);

const store = createStoreWithMiddleware(reducers);

export default store;
```

Any ideas what I can try from here?

Comment: Can't see from the code you've included, but given your `authenticate` action looks like a thunk is are you actually applying the `redux-thunk` middleware (or equivalent) to your redux store when creating it?

Comment: Hey thanks. Yes sorry its a thunk, and I have it in the store. I'll add that to the question.

Comment: @ZaidCrouch thanks! Your comment got me thinking and gave me the solution :-) Sometimes you just need one word from someone else. I needed to dispatch the function using `store.dispatch(authenticate())`, so I added `dispatch` to my `mapDispatchToProps` function. Since it was your insight, if you'd like to write it up as an answer, I'd be happy to accept it.